# POST method of request returns the name whose value has been truncated after spaces

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a calories app in which the user will select from a list of values (dropdown list) and then total calories consumed will be returned.

Now I have a form in which there are certain food items and the user can select them and they will be added to food items consumed by the user in the database.

The index.html file responsible for this action is as under:

```html
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %} 
                <select class="form-control" id="food_consumed" name="food_consumed">
                    {% for item in items %}
                        <option value={{item.item_name}}> 
                            {{item.item_name}}
                        </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success m-3"> Add </button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

The following view processes the data and stores it in the database:

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        food_item_name = request.POST.get('food_consumed')
        food_item = FoodModel.objects.filter(item_name = food_item_name)
        food_consumer = request.user
        food_item_consumed = Consumer(food_consumer = food_consumer, food_consumed = food_item)
        food_item_consumed.save()
    food_items = FoodModel.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'CaloriesApp/index.html', context={'items':food_items})
```

However, I am encountering a weird error. The value of the food_item_name gets truncated after spaces, that is to say that for instance I have a food item called Egg, raw (147g), the name returned will be: "Egg,". However, when there are no spaces in food items names, there is no issue in the app.

Also, when I use the Django Admin interface, everything works properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you log the food_item_name at your server in the post method? Does it display correctly there?

Comment: @SickerDude43 yes indeed. And it displays the truncated name i.e. if the item name is "Egg, raw" it displayed "Egg,"